# Pass java object to new android instance on list view click

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a list view populated by json returned from an api. As I parse the json I create a new java object that gets added to an array list. The array list is then used to build the list view. I can currentley click on an item in the list view and get a toast saying an item was clicked.

I would like to to be able to retrieve the individual object so I cna pass the object to a new instance and load all the objects details on a new instance to display to a user. How can I pass an object on like this?

My Code:

```
private class ReadJSONResult extends AsyncTask
    <String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                System.out.println(result);
                Log.d("asycTask", "[ Gets into asyc task ]");
                ///get 
                Log.d("search", "[ check if we get search results ]");
                Log.d("search", "[" + result + "]");

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                //acces listview
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                //make array list for beer
                List<BeerData> beerList = new ArrayList<BeerData>();



                //get json items
                for(int i = 0; i < json.getJSONArray("data").length(); i++) {

                    String beerId = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"id", json);
                    String beerName = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"name", json);
                    String beerDescription = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"description" , json);
                    String beerAbv = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"abv" , json);
                    String beerIbu = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"ibu" , json);
                    String beerIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "icon",json );
                    String beerMediumIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "medium",json );
                    String beerGlass = GetBeerGlassFromJSON(i, json );
                    String beerStyle = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"name", json );
                    String beerStyleDescription = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"description", json );
                    String beerBreweryId = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "id", json );
                    String beerBreweryName = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "name", json );
                    String beerBreweryDescription = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "description", json );
                    String beerBreweryWebsite = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "website", json );
                    String beerBreweryYear = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "established", json );



                    //create beer object
                    BeerData thisBeer = new BeerData(beerName, beerId, beerDescription, beerAbv, beerIbu, beerIcon,
                            beerMediumIcon, beerGlass, beerStyle, beerStyleDescription, beerBreweryId, beerBreweryName,
                            beerBreweryDescription, beerBreweryYear, beerBreweryWebsite);

                    //add beer to list
                    beerList.add(thisBeer);


                }

                //update listview
                ArrayAdapter<BeerData> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<BeerData>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.itemName, beerList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {

                        //on item click do this
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 
                    });






            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ReadBeerDataTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }          
        }
    }
```

Comment: use listview onitemClickListener and use this `lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2)`. where arg2 is the index position to get list item

Comment: simple!!! make `thisBeer` static and access it in any other class!!!!

Comment: @dd619 using static may not be good in this case

Comment: If you have access to the arraylist use the arg2(index) variable in the beerList to retreive the data. Later on if you want to pass an object to another activity make sure it is Serializable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your `BeerData` class implements the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface. Then just do :

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
              i.putExtra("myBeerObject", lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2));   
              startActivity(i); 
       } 
   });
```

From the second class :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
BeerData beer = b.getParcelable("myBeerObject");
```

Here's an [example](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.ch/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) of how to implement the interface correctly.

Comment: Awesome, I think I am close. I change my main part to this: http://pastebin.com/bfSsvwBs and my new class BeerPage.java is: http://pastebin.com/46CUxAeA but it keeps force closing when I click on an item

Comment: @Mike What did you cast it to (Boolean)  ? And call 
                `setContentView(R.layout.beer_page);` just after `super.onCreate` in your BeerPage activity.

Comment: @ZouZou if I didnt cast I got this error in eclipse: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)

Comment: @Mike Does your BeerData class implement the interface Parcelable ?

Comment: @Mike You have to complete the methods overriden. Please follow the example I gave you in the answer or this one: http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31939/discussion-between-mike-and-zouzou)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps to should allow you to do this:

Keep track of a `BeerData` collection. This would be `beerList` in your case.

Make `BeerData` implement `Parceable`.

(Use proper parameter names in `OnItemClick`. It should be `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`"

In onItemClick

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    var beerData = beerList[position];

    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("BEER!", beerData);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In NextActivities `onCreate`:

```
{
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    BeerData beerData = (BeerData) extras.getParcelable("BEER!);
}
```